# Entity to Map<String, Object>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I would like to clarify if it is possible to create `Map<String, Object>` from JPA entity through Hibernate. I mean is it possible to convert persistent object (entity) to Map that contains all entity properties as keys and properties' values as values. I understand that properties can be retrieved through Reflections but I can't figure out how to map it with proper values. I found only one solution and it is to use Spring's JdbcTemplate but it is not an option in my case. If anyone have possible solution please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using **@Converter** as follows

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity{
   @Id
   //...
   @Convert(converter = MyConverter.class)
   Map<String,Object> map;
}
```

and build up your converter as you wish for example convert to/from json

```
@Converter
public class MyConverter implements
AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String> {

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, Object> map) {
      return jsonStr(map);
}
@Override
public Map<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
     return mapFromJson(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the properties through reflection with the assistance of the [Apache BeanUtil](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) library, if your entity follows JavaBean naming conventions for all of its properties.

Step one: Wrap your entity in a [`WrapDynaBean`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/WrapDynaBean.html) object.

Step two: Create a [`DynaBeanPropertyMapDecorator`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/DynaBeanPropertyMapDecorator.html), further wrapping the DynaBean.

Step three: Well, that's it. `DynaBeanPropertyMapDecorator` implemements `Map<String, Object>` so your job is done there. `getFoo()` on your original object may now be found by `decorator.get("foo")`. (Note that you've lost type-safety here, but you *did* ask for a `Map<String, Object>`...)